# LINQ query to get top student (that has maximum score) in each course

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get a list of students who have scored maximum in a course. 
I have a student class and a course class as follows:

```
public class Student
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Level Year { get; set; }
    public List<Course> Courses;
}

public class Course
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

Student class has list of courses. And each course has Name and score.

Here is the datasource

```
public List<Student> students = new List<Student>
    {
        new Student {First="Svetlana", Last="Omelchenko", ID=111, Year = Level.First,
            Courses = new List<Course> {
                new Course { Name = "Maths", Score = 97 }, 
                new Course { Name = "Science", Score = 92}, 
                new Course { Name = "English", Score = 81}, 
                new Course { Name = "Arts", Score = 60}}},
        new Student {First="Claire", Last="O'Donnell", ID=112, Year = Level.First,
            Courses = new List<Course> {
                new Course { Name = "Maths", Score = 75 }, 
                new Course { Name = "Science", Score = 84}, 
                new Course { Name = "English", Score = 91}, 
                new Course { Name = "Arts", Score = 39}}},
        new Student {First="Sven", Last="Mortensen", ID=113, Year = Level.First,
            Courses = new List<Course> {
                new Course { Name = "Maths", Score = 88 }, 
                new Course { Name = "Science", Score = 94}, 
                new Course { Name = "English", Score = 65}, 
                new Course { Name = "Arts", Score = 91}}}, 
        new Student {First="Cesar", Last="Garcia", ID=114, Year = Level.First,
            Courses = new List<Course> {
                new Course { Name = "Maths", Score = 97 }, 
                new Course { Name = "Science", Score = 89}, 
                new Course { Name = "English", Score = 85}, 
                new Course { Name = "Arts", Score = 82}}},
        new Student {First="Debra", Last="Garcia", ID=115, Year = Level.First,
            Courses = new List<Course> {
                new Course { Name = "Maths", Score = 35 }, 
                new Course { Name = "Science", Score = 72}, 
                new Course { Name = "English", Score = 92}, 
                new Course { Name = "Arts", Score = 70}}},
        new Student {First="Fadi", Last="Fakhouri", ID=116, Year = Level.First,
            Courses = new List<Course> {
                new Course { Name = "Maths", Score = 99 }, 
                new Course { Name = "Science", Score = 86}, 
                new Course { Name = "English", Score = 90}, 
                new Course { Name = "Arts", Score = 94}}},
        new Student {First="Hanying", Last="Feng", ID=117, Year = Level.First,
            Courses = new List<Course> {
                new Course { Name = "Maths", Score = 93 }, 
                new Course { Name = "Science", Score = 92}, 
                new Course { Name = "English", Score = 80}, 
                new Course { Name = "Arts", Score = 87}}},
        new Student {First="Hugo", Last="Garcia", ID=118, Year = Level.First,
            Courses = new List<Course> {
                new Course { Name = "Maths", Score = 92 }, 
                new Course { Name = "Science", Score = 90}, 
                new Course { Name = "English", Score = 83}, 
                new Course { Name = "Arts", Score = 78}}},
        new Student {First="Lance", Last="Tucker", ID=119, Year = Level.First,
            Courses = new List<Course> {
                new Course { Name = "Maths", Score = 68 }, 
                new Course { Name = "Science", Score = 79}, 
                new Course { Name = "English", Score = 88}, 
                new Course { Name = "Arts", Score = 92}}},
        new Student {First="Terry", Last="Adams", ID=120, Year = Level.First,
            Courses = new List<Course> {
                new Course { Name = "Maths", Score = 99 }, 
                new Course { Name = "Science", Score = 82}, 
                new Course { Name = "English", Score = 81}, 
                new Course { Name = "Arts", Score = 79}}},
        new Student {First="Eugene", Last="Zabokritski", ID=121, Year = Level.First,
            Courses = new List<Course> {
                new Course { Name = "Maths", Score = 96 }, 
                new Course { Name = "Science", Score = 85}, 
                new Course { Name = "English", Score = 91}, 
                new Course { Name = "Arts", Score = 60}}},
        new Student {First="Michael", Last="Tucker", ID=122, Year = Level.First,
            Courses = new List<Course> {
                new Course { Name = "Maths", Score = 94 }, 
                new Course { Name = "Science", Score = 92}, 
                new Course { Name = "English", Score = 91}, 
                new Course { Name = "Arts", Score = 91}}}
    };
```

I'm trying to get an Output as follows:

```
Math:
    Fadi Fakhouri- 99
Science:
    Svetlana Omelchenko - 92
    Michael Tucker - 92
English:
    Debra Garcia - 92
Arts:
    Fadi Fakhouri - 94
```

What should my LINQ query look like?

Comment: have you done any research or googling on the `.MAX` function can you show us what you have attempted thus far on your own..? `SO is not a `Code Factory Site` please make a conscious effort / attempt at trying something on your own first then report back if you have any issues

Comment: @MethodMan Well, at least the OP went out of their way to supply sample data. Pretty good for a first question. A first shot at a solution would have skyrocketed the upvotes. Too bad, missed chance.

Comment: @GertArnold Posted code is good I agree.. but googling for Linq Max examples would have probably saved the OP a lot of time and trouble in my opinion. at least I didn't downvote it..

Comment: Thanks for looking at the code guys. I was asked this question in an interview and could not come up with an answer. I also tried it at home for a few hours (3 hours) to be exact. I could have put my wrong query here but that would have made everyone thought wrong first and then correct themselves after. But I like the @Ruskin 's solution. I will try to do it in a single LINQ query and post it here.

Comment: Next time show your own attempts nonetheless. It doesn't matter if they're wrong or tentative, but it's always highly appreciated if people have done their own due effort first. The community is particularly allergic to anything that smells like *please do my work for me*.

Comment: About the question itself. I think this could be easier if you start from the the source data that presumably come from some database. What you show now is a pre-aggregated set of data that must be dissected again to get the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below is one of MANY ways of doing it

```
var allCourses = students.SelectMany(s => s.Courses);
var groupedByCourse = allCourses.GroupBy(c => c.Name);  
foreach (var courseGroup in groupedByCourse)
{
    Console.WriteLine(courseGroup.Key + ":");
    int maxMark = courseGroup.Max(g => g.Score);
    var studentsWithMaxMark = students.Where(s => s.Courses.Any(c => c.Name == courseGroup.Key && c.Score == maxMark));
    foreach (var student in studentsWithMaxMark)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + student.First + " " + student.Last + " - " + maxMark);
    }
}
```

Outputs the following:

```
Maths:
  Fadi Fakhouri - 99
  Terry Adams - 99
Science:
  Sven Mortensen - 94
English:
  Debra Garcia - 92
Arts:
  Fadi Fakhouri - 94
```

The above IMO is explicit and quite readable.  You could potentially do the whole thing in one LINQ query.

Comment: Here is another way:

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way I got it using Linq only.

```
var query = from student in db.students
                    from course in student.Courses
                    group course by course.Name into g
                    select new
                    {
                        CourseName = g.Key,
                        Marks = g.Max(c => c.Score),
                        studentGroup = (
                            from student in db.students
                            let maxMark = g.Max(c => c.Score)
                            where student.Courses.Any(c => c.Name == g.Key && c.Score == maxMark)
                            select student
                        )
                    };

        foreach(var group in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Course: {0}", group.CourseName);
            foreach (var student in group.studentGroup)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0} {1} : {2}", student.First, student.Last, group.Marks);
            }
        }
```